# How to correctly save and load a model with custom CTC layer (Keras example)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ctc

I am following this tutorial on [Keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/) , but I don't know how to correctly save this model with custom layer *after the training* and load it.
This problem has been mentioned in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32348) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12373) but apparently non of those solutions work for this Keras example. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

P.S: here is the main part of the code:

```
class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # At test time, just return the computed predictions
        return y_pred


def build_model():
    # Inputs to the model
    input_img = layers.Input(
        shape=(img_width, img_height, 1), name="image", dtype="float32"
    )
    labels = layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,), dtype="float32")

    # First conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv1",
    )(input_img)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")(x)

    # Second conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv2",
    )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool2")(x)

    # We have used two max pool with pool size and strides 2.
    # Hence, downsampled feature maps are 4x smaller. The number of
    # filters in the last layer is 64. Reshape accordingly before
    # passing the output to the RNN part of the model
    new_shape = ((img_width // 4), (img_height // 4) * 64)
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name="reshape")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense1")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    # RNNs
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)

    # Output layer
    x = layers.Dense(len(characters) + 1, activation="softmax", name="dense2")(x)

    # Add CTC layer for calculating CTC loss at each step
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
    )
    # Optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    # Compile the model and return
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model


# Get the model
model = build_model()
model.summary()class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # At test time, just return the computed predictions
        return y_pred


def build_model():
    # Inputs to the model
    input_img = layers.Input(
        shape=(img_width, img_height, 1), name="image", dtype="float32"
    )
    labels = layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,), dtype="float32")

    # First conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv1",
    )(input_img)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")(x)

    # Second conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv2",
    )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool2")(x)

    # We have used two max pool with pool size and strides 2.
    # Hence, downsampled feature maps are 4x smaller. The number of
    # filters in the last layer is 64. Reshape accordingly before
    # passing the output to the RNN part of the model
    new_shape = ((img_width // 4), (img_height // 4) * 64)
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name="reshape")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense1")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    # RNNs
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)

    # Output layer
    x = layers.Dense(len(characters) + 1, activation="softmax", name="dense2")(x)

    # Add CTC layer for calculating CTC loss at each step
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
    )
    # Optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    # Compile the model and return
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model


# Get the model
model = build_model()
model.summary()

epochs = 100
early_stopping_patience = 10
# Add early stopping
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=early_stopping_patience, restore_best_weights=True
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
)

# Get the prediction model by extracting layers till the output layer
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
prediction_model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not actually with Keras's saving methods. The `characters` set is inconsistent and does not keep ordering. Add the below code after creating the `characters` set to solve the issue:

```
characters = sorted(list(characters))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amirhosein, check out this function in the Horovod repository:

Serialize:
https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/6f0bb9fae826167559501701d4a5a0380284b5f0/horovod/spark/keras/util.py#L115

Deserialize:
https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/6f0bb9fae826167559501701d4a5a0380284b5f0/horovod/spark/keras/remote.py#L267

Example of use for deserialization:
https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/6f0bb9fae826167559501701d4a5a0380284b5f0/horovod/spark/keras/remote.py#L118

If you are using custom objects like custom metrics or custom Loss function, you will need to use `custom_object_scope` as in the example.

It used a package called cloudpickle (https://pypi.org/project/cloudpickle/) under the hood to convert the KerasModel to a string and vice versa.